# How do I make an updating form submit button in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am making a SvelteKit app, and it's basically a bunch of forms that the server processes. I have a button component that changes its text on click to 'Loading' and disables itself after submission or if the parent component tells it to (for client-side form validation).

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let valid = true;
    let submitting = false;
    let clicked = false;
    function click() {
        clicked = true;
        // hacky workaround to disable self but still work as a submit button
        setTimeout(() => {
            submitting = true;
        }, 0);
    }
</script>

<button type="submit" disabled={!valid || submitting} on:click={click}>
    {#if clicked}
        Loading...
    {:else}
        {valid ? 'Submit' : 'Incomplete Form'}
    {/if}
</button>
```

So far so good, but I can't figure out how to reset it after it receives data back from a form action. I'm thinking maybe I use `afterUpdate` or something? I don't really know.

Comment: Would not recommend disabling the button due to form being invalid. It is less accessible as disabled elements are not interactive. and may not show up in assistive technology as easily. Also, standard form validation mechanisms show validation issues on submit attempts, without a submit button (that is enabled), no submit attempt can be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the state as another property and update that from the outside based on the form state. If you use the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance) you can use that to update the state.

Something like:

```html
<script>
  // ...

  let submitting = false;
  function onSubmit() {
    submitting = true;

    return ({ update }) => {
      submitting = false;
      update();      
    };
  }
</script>

<form use:enhance={onSubmit}>
   ...
   <Button disabled={submitting} ...
```